# How do I name these php variables

Tags: php

I want to use a forloop to create a number of vars... their names are `$var1` to `$var15`. How do I do that? I'm doing `$$var.$i` but it's not working.

```
for($i=1; $i <= 15; $i++){
   $$var.$i = 'this is the content of var'.$i;
}
```

Comment: very similar question: [Print a variable through a 'for' in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7296381)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to do that, exactly, you would have to do `${$var . $i}` instead. Right now it's being interpreted as `($$var).$i`.

However, this is very bad style. Instead, you should use an array<sup>[[php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)]</sup> to store the values:

```
$var = array();
for($i=1; $i <= 15; $i++){
    $var[$i] = 'This is the content of $var['.$i.'].';
}

var_export($var);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'This is the content of $var[1].',
  2 => 'This is the content of $var[2].',
  3 => 'This is the content of $var[3].',
  4 => 'This is the content of $var[4].',
  5 => 'This is the content of $var[5].',
  6 => 'This is the content of $var[6].',
  7 => 'This is the content of $var[7].',
  8 => 'This is the content of $var[8].',
  9 => 'This is the content of $var[9].',
  10 => 'This is the content of $var[10].',
  11 => 'This is the content of $var[11].',
  12 => 'This is the content of $var[12].',
  13 => 'This is the content of $var[13].',
  14 => 'This is the content of $var[14].',
  15 => 'This is the content of $var[15].',
)
```

This is more efficient and often safer.

Comment: +1: For actually answering the question before providing an alternative.